# How do I call a mongoose Schema function with Restangular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, restangular, bcrypt

I'm new to MEAN development, and I'm using bcrypt to encrypt the password from UserSchema (everything works wonders), but since I have to authenticate from the client side I've made a function to the UserSchema:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};
```

Now.. how do I call this function from the client side? 
I'm using Restangular, and I'm trying something like this:

```
function authLogin() {
  if(vm.user && vm.user.email && vm.user.password){

    User.getList({ email: vm.user.email }).then(function(user){

        user.comparePassword(vm.user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(vm.user.password, isMatch);
        });
    });
}}
```

But then occurs an error saying that *user* doesn't have the funciton:

> user.comparePassword is not a function

So, what is wrong about it? Or it is not possible to call a Schema function directly from the client side?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your immediate question (if i understand which of your code samples lives to which layer): why is it "not possible to call a Schema function directly from the client side" is that the server and client side javascript run in a completely different context so functions you might declare in server-side models or middleware are not available to your client context.

The general solution to "call a schema function" from the client side with node and javascript frameworks is to POST or GET data to a server-side API endpoint and then you call your schema methods within the API code (or middleware attached to that API endpoint).

I would suggest that you take a look at the https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport passport authentication API module which is a market standard way to handle client authentication that you should be able to pretty easily bolt onto your application.